# Accessing child class members using pointer to parent in C

Tags: c

why does this work?

```
typedef struct {
   data member_x;
} base;

typedef struct {
   struct base;
   data member_y;
} derived;
```

`void function_on_base(struct base * a);` // here I can pass both pointers to derived and to base, how am I able to do so?

How can function_on_base that require a pointer of time base to accept a pointer of type derived?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Why/How does this work? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because in memory, the `derived` struct can be represented as this :

```
             sizeof(derived)
     sizeof(base)
|-------------------|----------------|

beginning           end of base      end of derived
of derived
AND of base
```

So this:

```
derived my_derived;
(base)my_derived;
```

will actually take the `sizeof(base)` first bytes of `derived`, which is equivalent to the `base struct` (since you declared it in first position in your `derived` struct).

When you call your function, an **implicit cast** is done without your knowledge and simply works. You should compile with some additional flags to avoid those implicit casts.

Though, this functionality is mainly used in C because it allows to "reproduce" **OOP** functionalities, existing in languages like `C++`.